# How to join two tables and return all column values if foreign_key id present or return null if foreign key id not present in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, left-join, sql-server-2016

I have four tables

```
applicationmaster, projectdetails, clientdetails, employeedetails
```

I have a stored procedure to return all the columns by joining these four tables like - applicationmaster may have employee or may not have employee.

applicationmaster and employee details both are mapped with app_id. I want to retrieve all the data from employeedetails table if app_id present and if not present then return null for all the columns of employee details

```
  applicationmaster                                   employeedetails

  app_id | app_name | cotractor                       emp_id | app_id | emp_name | emp_designation
   1         BPM       X                              101        1      Tony           Manager
   2         CRM       Y                              102        1      Mark           Consultant
   3         Portal    Z
```

Here, I have two employee for app_id 1. so I want to retrieve like:

```
   1  BPM   X   101     Tony    Manager
   1  BPM   X   102     Mark    Consultant
   2  CRM   Y   null    null    null
   3  Portal Z  null    null    null
```

But my stored procedure is returning only those rows from applicationmaster table which has employees.

Like only first two row getting returned from my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Dashboard_SowReport]
AS  
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        am.app_id AS 'App Id',
        cd.app_name AS 'App Name',
        cd.scheduler_name AS 'Scheduler Name',
        pd.project_name AS 'Project Name',
        pd.Project_id AS 'Project Id',
        MONTH(am.app_end_date) AS 'App Expiring Month',
        DATEDIFF(Day,am.app_start_date,am.app_end_date) AS 'Contract due in days',
        ed.associate_name AS 'Associate Name',
        ed.emp_id AS 'EID',
        ed.client_id AS 'Client Id',
        ed.bill_rate_per_hour AS 'Bill Rate'
    FROM
        applicationMaster am
    JOIN
        projectdetails pd ON (am.project_id = pd.project_id)
    JOIN
        clientdetails cd ON (cd.client_id = pd.client_id)
    JOIN 
        employeedetails ed ON (ed.app_id = am.app_id)
END
```

Can someone help me here please? I am learning to write and optimised SQL queries

Thank you

Comment: Just by having "join" you are doing an inner join. Need left join

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Noted. Thanks marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a `left join`. Your query and your sample data do not properly relate - for your sample data, this would be:

```
select m.*, e.emp_name, e.emp_designation
from applicationmaster m
left join employeedetails e on e.app_id = a.app_id
```

Comment: Oh Jesus, I was missing this left join. Thank you so much GMB